# How do I erase internal EEPROM on a Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, eeprom

I'm working on Arduino pro mini.
and I store some data in internal EEPROM.

So, I want to erase certain data from 0x00 to 0x28 address in EEPROM.

```
void loop()
{
 ...
 ...
 if(erase_eeprom_flag==1)
 {
   addr_uu=0;
          erase_eeprom_flag=0;
          for(kk=0;kk<28;kk++)
          {
              EEPROM.update(addr_uu,0);

              addr_uu=addr_uu+1;

          }
          Serial.println("OK");  
          Serial.println(addr_uu,DEC);
          addr_uu=0;
      }
  }
```

But I got a data like(28 times '0' and other data 'xxx') "0000000000000000000000000000xxxxxxxxxxxx".

ex : 20170519    --->   expected data: 00000519 
                        (inappropriate data: 000020170519)

So, here actually push "0" / add at begin operation happen but I want to remove data from those address.

Please tell which Arduino function help me for solving my issue.

Answer (score 4):

You are clearing 28 decimal bytes, but your address range is 28 hex bytes, or 40 bytes of data.  Hence, the last 12 characters are untouched.

Comment: 41 bytes (decimal), counting the zero-th byte. Regardless, good catch.